# Can't change Number.prototype in typescript 1.7.3

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

I used to be able to do this in Ts 1.0 but now I get the error `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Number'`

```
Number.prototype.foo = function(foo) {
    return true
};
```

UPDATE

so far none of the answers below have worked for me. I'm using ts-loader and babel

Answer (score 3):

Add a declaration to add the member to `Number`:

```
interface Number {
    foo(): boolean;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I also do it for Number.prototype.test(min, max) that returns a number?

Comment: @CodeiSir I get  error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Number'.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper  `TS2339` maybe fell in the same trap as I did. Any `import` or `export` statement in that file ? See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5944

Comment: @SuperUberDuper I posted an answer where the complete code is working

Comment: @CodeiSir there are 5 exports in that file, I moved it to the top level Main.ts file and it works. (entry point to webpack ts-loader)

Comment: I think its caused by ts-loader?

Answer (score 3):

Or, take the coward's way out and go `Number.prototype['foo']=`

You won't get any type checking, but then again if you wanted type checking you'd have added it. It's worth knowing about `foo['bar']` as a quick fix for "Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'foo'"

Comment: but it wont give him any type-support

Comment: that's correct, which is why I called it the coward's way out. Not all devs want everything typed all of the time.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify it, in case someone was wondering ;-) Maybe put it in your answer, and I'll delete the comments

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Number { test(min, max): number; }    

Number.prototype.test = function (min, max) { return 0 };

// Examples:
(1).test(0, 0)

var a = 1
a.test(0, 0)
```

Live Code: [typescriptlang.org/Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20Number%20%7B%20test(min%2C%20max)%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%0ANumber.prototype.test%20%3D%20function%20(min%2C%20max)%20%7B%20return%200%20%7D%3B%20%0A%0A(1).test(0%2C%200)%0A%0Avar%20a%20%3D%201%0Aa.test(0%2C%200))

Comment: for some reason this still doesn't work for me: error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Number'. ts v 1.7

Comment: Wow you are right, for some reason the semicolon is needed: `Number.prototype.test = function (min, max) { return 0 };` ...

Comment: when I click run it takes me to another page.

Comment: I don't know why the link would not work for you. But there is only the same code again

Comment: the ts playground never run for me. Seems broken on the mac

Comment: :D I hope you don't use Safari ;) Is you problem solved by the way?